# How to target the parent element when creating input fields based on fetched data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This is how my JSON looks like for you to get an idea:

```
{
  "main_object": {
   "id": "0",
   "getExerciseTitle": "TestToConfirm",
   "language": "nl_NL",
   "application": "lettergrepen",
"main_object": {
  "title": "TestToConfirm",
  "language": "nl_NL",
  "exercises": [
    {
      "word": "huisarts",
      "syllables": [
        "huis",
        "arts"
      ]
    },
    {
      "word": "huisartsenpraktijk",
      "syllables": [
        "huis",
        "artsen",
        "praktijk"
      ]
    },
    {
      "word": "testikels",
      "syllables": [
        "test",
        "ikels"
      ]
    },
    {
      "word": "Graag gedaan. v",
      "syllables": [
        "graag",
        "gedaan"
      ]
    }
  ]
},
"dataType": "json"
 }
}
```

as you can see I have a `word` with `syllables`. I managed to create input fields based on the length of my `syllables`, but the input fields duplicate 9 times for each row (note, as u can see there are 9 words within the `syllables` total. I am trying to get the `syllables` to append in the row of their `word` (what I assume is their parent?). This is how my code looks like right now:

```
function createExercise(json) {
  const exercises = json.main_object.main_object.exercises;
  exercises.forEach(function(exercise) {
var exer = $('<div/>', {
    'class': 'row'
  })
  .append(
    $('<div/>', {
      'class': 'col-md-3'
    })
    .append(
      $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'row'
      })
      .append($('<div>', {
        class: 'col-md-3 audioButton'
      }))
      .append($('<div>', {
        class: 'col-md-9 ExerciseWordFontSize exerciseWord',
        'id': 'wordInput[' + ID123 + ']',
        text: exercise.word
      }))
    )
  ).append(
    $('<div>', {
      class: 'col-md-9'
    })
    .append(
        $('<div/>', {
            class: 'row'
        }))
    .append($('<div/>', {
        class: 'col-md-3 inputSyllables'
    }))
  );

$("#exerciseField").append(exer);
ID123++;
exer.find('.audioButton').append(getAudioForWords());

  });

  exercises.forEach(function(exercise) {
   lengthsyllables = exercise.syllables.length;
   console.log(lengthsyllables);
   for (l = 0; l < lengthsyllables; l++) {
    var getInputField = $('<input/>', {
        'type': 'text',
        'class': 'form-group form-control col-md-3',
        'name': 'inputSyllables'
       });
    $('.inputSyllables').append(getInputField);
      }
     });
   }
```

a picture: [image]

Comment: You are appending each syllabes to class .inputSyllables, so you will have as many inputs as syllabes you have on your object (9). Try to give an unique Id and append to a div with this id. Hope it helps

Comment: Whenever I try to give it a unique ID it sets them all to 0. it doesn't add +1

Comment: You can use the second parameter of forEach, which is index, so you can create your unique id depending of the position of the array.